Why are airbnb rules not being applied in my eslint configuration with flat config?
I'm trying to set up ESLint with Airbnb rules and TypeScript support using the new flat config format. However, it seems that the Airbnb rules are not being applied to my codebase.
Here's the configuration I'm using:
import js from "@eslint/js";
import pluginTs from "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin";
import parserTs from "@typescript-eslint/parser";
import pluginVue from "eslint-plugin-vue";
import globals from "globals";
import airbnbBase from "eslint-config-airbnb-base";
import airbnbBaseTypescript from "eslint-config-airbnb-base-typescript";

export default [
  js.configs.recommended,
  {
    files: ["**/*.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,vue}"],
    languageOptions: {
      globals: globals.browser,
      parser: parserTs,
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020,
        sourceType: "module",
        project: "./tsconfig.json",
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      "@typescript-eslint": pluginTs,
      vue: pluginVue,
    },
    rules: {
      ...airbnbBase.rules,
      ...airbnbBaseTypescript.rules,
    },
  },
  {
    files: ["**/*.vue"],
    languageOptions: {
      parserOptions: {
        parser: parserTs,
      },
    },
    rules: {
      "vue/max-attributes-per-line": "off",
      "vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline": "off",
    },
  },
];

Despite this setup, it appears that the Airbnb rules are not being applied. The only rules being enforced are related to TypeScript and Vue, but not the Airbnb rules.
What could be causing this issue? Are there any additional steps I need to take to ensure that Airbnb rules are properly applied in a flat config setup?
